# How to lazyload js file on first user interection only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

How to lazy load .js file on first user interection?

I want to lazyload some external js file on first user interection (it won't load until user interected to screen like scroll, touchstart, mouseover)

I know it is possible but it is something tricky that I'm not able to do with my basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.createElement("script");  
element.src = "script.js";  
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function bubu(){ // document - mousemove
  let script = document.createElement('img'); // (script)
  
  script.src = "https://i.gyazo.com/fe48322c44d1c214ee8d9ba49876a0da.png" // JS file
  
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  
  btn.removeEventListener('click', bubu); // works only once.
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Interact!</button><br>
```

Used img tag just for demo. They will work identically.

Comment: is it possible without using a button? on someone scroll

Comment: @Uzair `window.addEventListener('scroll', func...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function addJs(){
 let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = '/js/custom.js';
            script.id = 'customjs'
            script.defer = true;
            script.async = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
btn.removeEventListener('click', addJs);
});
```